# WebDav 409 Error

Tags: c#, iis, webdav

I am trying to add multiple files using WebDav.  The directory I am trying to upload to is empty.

I loop through the files and sent the files.

1 Add doc1.txt to WebDav Server using HTTP Put 
  -- Success always even if the files is already there.

2 Add doc2.txt to WebDav Server using HTTP Put
 -- Always fails with a 409 error.

It does not matter what file or order I process the files it always fails on the second file.
Anyone have and idea?

Here is the method I am using:

```
public static bool UploadFile(string url, string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return false;
    }

    long fileLen = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;

    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    Request.Credentials = mCredentials;
    Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;

    Request.ContentLength = fileLen;
    Request.SendChunked = true;

    // Specify that overwriting the destination is allowed.
    Request.Headers.Add(@"Overwrite", @"T");
    Request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

    System.IO.Stream stream = Request.GetRequestStream();

    FileStream fileStrem = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    int transferRate = 4096;
    byte[] data = new byte[transferRate];
    int read = 0;
    long totalRead = 0;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            read = fileStrem.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (read > 0)
            {
                totalRead += read;
                stream.Write(data, 0, read);
            }
        } while (read > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
        stream = null;

        fileStrem.Close();
        fileStrem.Dispose();
        fileStrem = null;
    }

    HttpWebResponse Response;
    try
    {
        Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Response == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error accessing Url " + url);
            throw;
        }

        HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;

        //if the file has not been modified
        if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
        {
            e.Response.Close();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Response.Close();
            Debug.WriteLine("Error accessing Url " + url);
            throw;
        }
    }
    //This case happens if no lastmodedate was specified, but the specified
    //file does exist on the server. 
    Response.Close();

    if (totalRead == fileLen)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 7 questions, 0% accepted.  Please go back and accept some answers.

Comment: Show the code you are using that gives you the error.

Comment: I figured it out.  I will post the solution when I can answer my own question.  Problem was I was concatenating the file name on the url so the resource didn't exist on the server.

Answer (score 6):

This is a stupid mistake on my part.  WebDave documentation say, "A PUT that would result in the creation of a resource without an appropriately scoped parent collection MUST fail with a 409 (Conflict).".

Well I was looping through my files and concatenating the file name instead of just replacing the file name.

This is how I was calling UploadFile:

```
string url = "http://someurl"

foreach (string file in files)
{
    url = url.TrimEnd(new char[] { '/' }) + @"/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
    UploadFile(url, file);
    fileCount++;
}
```

When I changed it to this it work:

```
string url = "http://someurl"
string temp;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    temp = url.TrimEnd(new char[] { '/' }) + @"/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
    UploadFile(temp, file);
    fileCount++;
}
```

Comment: Can you reply what is url  example in your method. Like "http://someurl/uploadefile".so what is uploadefile method or folder name.Can you give and explain valid url to use your method. I am getting 405 method not allowed error.